TypeOrm - Many to Many on the same table
I have this Users entity
@Entity()
export class Users {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  nickName: string;

  @Column()
  phone: string;

  @Column()
  jwtToken: string;

  @Column()
  socketId: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Contacts, (x) => x.userId)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'contacts',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'userId',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'id',
    },
  })
  contacts: Users[];
}

and I want to make a many to many relationship using this entity for a chat app (user with a friends list)
the join table is
@Entity()
export class Contacts {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  userId: number;

  @Column()
  contactId: number;
}

[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "nickName": null,
        "phone": "40724640324",
        "jwtToken": "",
        "socketId": "",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "userId": 6,
                "contactId": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "nickName": null,
        "phone": "40720527102",
        "jwtToken":",
        "socketId": "",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "userId": 7,
                "contactId": 6
            }
        ]
    }
]

this is the response i'm getting from the api but I also want to add the contact id in the contacts array. How can i achieve this?
I've tried adding
@ManyToMany(type => Users, user => user.contacts)
  contactInfo: Users

